# How to get MaterialDropdownSelectSimpleDemoComponent from AngularDart Gallery to work in a simple AngularDart Project

Tags: angular-material, angular-dart

I’m new to AngularDart and am trying to add a dropdown selector to my project. I’m looking at the examples in the AngularDart Gallery, specifically: https://dart-lang.github.io/angular_components/#/material_dropdown_select

I’ve gone back to “basics” and created a new project using the IntelliJ IDEA > New Project > Dart > AngularDart Web App. The “My First AngularDart App” (a todo_list app) builds and runs OK.

So then to add a dropdown selector, after trying various approaches, I’ve added the demo code from the AngularDart Gallery to this project:

- On the URL above, clicked “Source Code” next to MaterialDropdownSelectSimpleDemoComponent
- Went up one level in the repository and copied the contents of material_dropdown_select_simple_demo (.dart, .html and .scss) into my project
- [Problem 1] As an aside, I actually went up multiple levels until I could Clone dart-lang/angular_components. But I can’t get this to build as a project so that I can play with it “live” which might help. Am I missing something obvious here??
- So I have a material_dropdown_select_simple_component.dart, .html, .scss in my project and updated the @Component selector: templateUrl: and stryleUrls: to match my component name
- Then in the main component in the project (app_component.html) I add:

```
<material-dropdown-select-simple-component></material-dropdown-select-simple-component>
```

- And add the MaterialDropdownSelectSimpleDemoComponent class name to the directives: and add the associated import statement
- Add to dependencies in pubspec.yaml (due to the use of scss)

```
sass_builder: ^2.0.0
```

I then try to run it and get:

```
[SEVERE] build_web_compilers|entrypoint on web/main.dart:
Unable to find modules for some sources, this is usually the result of either a
bad import, a missing dependency in a package (or possibly a dev_dependency
needs to move to a real dependency), or a build failure (if importing a
generated file).

Please check the following imports:

`import 'package:DropDownSelectv4/src/todo_list/material_dropdown_select_simple_component.scss.css.shim.dart' as import0;` from DropDownSelectv4|lib/src/todo_list/material_dropdown_select_simple_component.template.dart at 10:1
```

[Problem 2]
So I have a line number in a template.dart file, and I can’t find this file.

[Problem 3]
In reviewing the code, I notice that in the material_drop_select_simple_component.scss there are red squiggles under:

```
@import 'package:angular_components/css/material/material';
@import 'package:angular_components/css/material/shadow';
```

Maybe I am missing a dependency in my pubspec.yaml file, but how do I determine what?
I currently have:

```
dependencies:
  angular: ^5.2.0
  angular_components: ^0.11.0
  sass_builder: ^2.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  angular_test: ^2.2.0
  build_runner: ^1.1.2
  build_test: ^0.10.3
  build_web_compilers: ^1.0.0
  pedantic: ^1.0.0
  test: ^1.5.1
```

I’m thinking that I am missing something basic here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Problem 1] As an aside, I actually went up multiple levels until I
>   could Clone dart-lang/angular_components. But I can’t get this to
>   build as a project so that I can play with it “live” which might help.
>   Am I missing something obvious here??

The only fully fledged package in the repo that you can build and experiment with locally is called angular_components_example. It is the package that builds the example gallery.
https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/tree/master/examples/angular_components_example

> [Problem 2] So I have a line number in a template.dart file, and I
>   can’t find this file.

Files that are generated during your build like .template.dart (by angular) or .css (by sass_builder) will be located in a hidden directory at the root of your  package called `.dart_tool/build/generated/<your package name>`

> [Problem 3] In reviewing the code, I notice that in the
>   material_drop_select_simple_component.scss there are red squiggles
>   under...

I think the red squiggles are actually red herrings and you shouldn't worry about those imports. They are from a little workaround we created to allow you to import sass files with knowledge of the dart package system and there isn't any integration with IDEs to support the imports.

I think the real problem is the name of the sass file in your `material_dropdown_select_simple_component.dart` file. Change the line to:

```
styleUrls: [material_dropdown_select_simple_component.css]
```

By default the sass_builder package compiles `.scss` files in your package to `.css` files. (we just use a different convention within the angular_components package so when you copied the file it probably has `.scss.css` in it.

Comment: Thankyou - that has taken me to the next step. I can build the angular gallery, which seems to work EXCEPT the link to Material Dropdown Select. In the browser console I find: `2:8080/packages/$sdk/dev_compiler/amd/dart_sdk.js:18676 SEVERE: OverlayService must be a singleton: Check that there is no nested overlayBindings or popupBindings
:8080/packages/$sdk/dev_compiler/amd/dart_sdk.js:100398 EXCEPTION: Expected a value of type '(dynamic) => String', but got one of type '(HasUIDisplayName) => String'`. Any further help would be appreciated. I'm getting a similar error in my project.

Comment: Sorry about that. There was a bug in the example that has now been fixed. https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/commit/bb90a364e36170d22972a5a66f9895604b25d885 The master branch has been updated so if you sync it should work.

Comment: Thanks that solved it!. I haven't been able to get the angular_components_example to rebuild due to it now requiring: SDK version >=2.2.1-dev.3.0. (I tried to upgrade and failed!). However, I was able to apply the changes made to material_dropdown_select_full_demo.dart and .html in my project and all seems fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following two links help you.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44230452/how-to-use-material-dropdown-select-in-angular-dart
https://dart-lang.github.io/angular_components/#/material_dropdown_select
```

Comment: Thanks that helped - but ultimately it turned out to be a bug in the example in the AngularDart Gallery.